# Save instance which extended from Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have an entity which defines a employee table. For the project structure, There are some subclasses like `"EmployeeTrn"`,`"EmployeeBck"`,... which are just extended from `Employee` super class. All of attributes and methods are exactly same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;

   @Column(name = "salary")
   private int salary;  

   public Employee() {}
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }
   public void setId( int id ) {
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }
   public void setFirstName( String first_name ) {
      this.firstName = first_name;
   }
   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }
   public void setLastName( String last_name ) {
      this.lastName = last_name;
   }
   public int getSalary() {
      return salary;
   }
   public void setSalary( int salary ) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }
}
```

Extended subclasses are like below.

```
public class EmployeeTrn extends Employee{
        public EmployeeTrn(){
            id = Builder.generateSSI();
            firstName = Helper.fetchFromLocal("8091").name();
            lastName = Helper.fetchFromLocal("8091").surname();
        }
    }


public class EmployeeBck extends Employee{
            public EmployeeBck(){
                id = Builder.generateSSIFromHost("localhost:8091");
                firstName = Helper.fetchFromAWS("/token.dat").name();
                lastName = Helper.fetchFromAWS("/token.dat").surname();
            }
        }
```

I have already map Employee entity on configuration xml file. But the **problem** appears when i try to save classes which are extended from Employee.

```
session.saveEmployee(employeeTrn);

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.company.EmployeeTrn
```

Can anyone help me? I am stuck.

Comment: what do you mean by instance? what are you trying to reach with extending from an entity class?

Comment: @pouyankhodabakhsh due to project structure, i should extended instances like EmployeeTrn, etc. This extended subclasses have exactly same attributes and methods as super has. The reason to use this, each subclasses has different attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

your subclass entity should be defined to be entity as well, since you did not define your inheritance type, the inheritance strategy will be single table , which means your super class and it's children will be mapped to the same table, so it makes sense that you should be defining the entity of the subclass.

```
@Entity
public class EmployeeTrn extends Employee{
    public EmployeeTrn(){
        id = Builder.generateSSI();
        firstName = Helper.fetchFromLocal("8091").name();
        lastName = Helper.fetchFromLocal("8091").surname();
    }
```

Comment: But EmployeeTrn should not be Entity. For project structure different instances like EmployeeTrn are initialized with different params. So after each instance are created, I want to save Employee, which is super class of instances. I think my problem is like a typecasting, but don't know how to solve :/

Comment: To have hibernate recognize your class it should be entity, now the inheritance strategy defines what you are trying to accomplish, if you are trying to just map the parent , then why do you even need the children? imagine your parent has 10 attributes and your children has 12 attribute, if the parent is the only one mapped (this cannot happen) then the 2 more attributes which are in the children and not the parent will be lost

Comment: Subclasses are exactly same as super class has. I have updated questing. Each subclass has different attribute values. Like EmployeeTrn.name = "EmployeeTrnHolland", EmployeeBck.name="EmployeeBckAsia"...

Comment: if they have the same attributes and the difference in the value then this is a misuse of inheritence, what you need here is a strategy, read about strategy design pattern, anyway that is how hibernate works, even the subclasses should be defined as entity

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Did not recognize the entity. So, you need map the **EmployeeTrn** entity too:

See the Inheritance configuration: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance